# @Value default null value not working after spring upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

An application that was using an older version of spring was migrated to springboot 2.2.4 release.

After the upgrade, it is not picking up the property value here :

```
@Value("${stuff.value:#{null}}")
```

The value gets picked if I remove the :#{null} from the expression. 
Any idea why this worked fine in older spring version but not now.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
@Value("${stuff.value:null}")
```

Answer (score 0):

`#{null}` is support from Spring Expression Language (SpEL). Maybe this library is not available in your dependency.